# google custom search engine does'nt show all keywords in autocompletion

Tags: autocomplete, search-engine

I have an isuue on my site. I set google search engine to autocompletion, so when user types any key the related keywords display, but my google search box doesn't show all keywords, and only display a few keywords. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What makes you say that not all keywords are shown? Keep in mind that google custom search engine will not show the same results as google.com.

Answer (score 0):

1. It may be because of low Internet connection speed
2. Of course google website autocompletion result is NOT the same with result from  google custom autocompletion